# Django Rest: Inter nested relationship for serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two serializers, and wish to embed one in another. The problem is one declared below in the file is not found by the one above.

```
class SprintSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)  #Is not found 
    class Meta:
        model = Sprint
        fields = ('id' , 'name' , 'description' , 'end' , 'tasks')

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sprint = SprintSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) #Is found
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id' , 'name' , 'description' , 'sprint' , 'status' , )
```

The TaskSerializer uses SprintSerializer which is fine because its found. But SprintSerializer can't find TaskSerializer as its declared after its use.

Error encountered:
NameError at /api/tasks/2/
name 'TaskSerializer' is not defined

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you expecting the output to look like when a Task or Sprint is serialized? Your issue is that Django REST framework is trying to avoid an infinite recursion loop, which I'm fairly confident would happen if this worked.